# Slick2d Image object not displaying correctly?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I just started using the Slick2d game library (following [this](http://goo.gl/Chf8u) guide). For some reason the whole frame is black. I don't know what's wrong, because I'm getting complaints from neither Eclipse nor Slick2d.

Here is a screenshot of my project tree:

[image: My project tree]

Here is the *Game.java* source:

```
package com.michael.ivorymoon;

import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class Game extends BasicGame
{
    Image land = null;
    Image plane = null;
    float x = 400;
    float y = 300;
    float scale = 1.0f;

    public Game()
    {
        super("Ivory Moon");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer container) throws SlickException
    {
        land = new Image("/res/land.jpg");
        land.draw(0, 0);
        plane = new Image("/res/plane.png");
        plane.draw(x, y, scale);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) throws SlickException
    {
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics graphics) throws SlickException
    {
        ;       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException
    {
        AppGameContainer appContainer = new AppGameContainer(new Game());

        appContainer.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
        appContainer.start();
    }
}
```

You can find `/res/land.jpg` over [here](http://s24.postimg.org/bcyf2hqpx/background.jpg). This is `/res/plane.jpg`:

[image: /res/plane.jpg]

And finally, just in case you didn't believe me, here is the running application:

[image: Running application; no images displayed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 land = new Image("/res/land.jpg");
```

and

```
 land = new Image("/res/plane.png");
```

are the culprit, the leading `/` states you want to start at the base of your filesystem, an absolute path.  Try using:

```
 land = new Image("res/land.jpg");
 land = new Image("res/plane.png");
```

This path is relative to your project, should work.

Also, draw calls need to be made within render method.

Comment: I tried that, same result. Black screen. No complaints about it not existing in either case. But if I rename the `res` folder then it complains, which I suppose means both are valid. What else could be the problem?

Comment: Are you running from eclipse or through console / package?

Comment: Sounds dumb, but try doing a Project -> Clean making sure you don't lead with a /

Comment: Still nothing. Are you familiar with the Slick2d library?

Comment: Little bit, I believe the problem actually is related to where you're calling draw.  If you look down on the tutorial, the draw call is within the render method, which, if I remember from when I went through this a while ago, is a callback of the BasicGame base class.  Put your render logic within there, and your init should only contain your new'ing of objects.  My file path stuff is still relevant, it might be you just have a folder under C:/res/plane.png etc.

Comment: Well there it goes! I must have missed that small detail in the tutorial, but I suppose it makes the most sense! Thanks for finding my stupid mistake, mate!